# SQL Data From Prior Month End Row During Current Month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking to get the # of employees listed during the current month shown with the number of employees from the last day of the prior month from a SQL Server Query.

So for every day in September, I want to show the number of active employees from the August 31st row under PMActive.  Here is the select part of the SQL Query.  Active total is in Table 1.  Dates are in Table 2.

```
CAST(T2.Calendar_Date AS date) AS CalDate,
CAST(DATEADD(D,-(DAY(AD.Calendar_Date)),AD.Calendar_Date) AS date) AS PMEndDate,
T1.Active AS Active,
FROM F_Table1 T1
LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON Date=Date
```

I can't seem to code to get this data field without getting a NULL or the current day active employees.   This is how the output should look.

**Data output**

[image]

Comment: so can you get CalDate, PmEnddate and active?  Because then you could CROSS APPLY to a query that gets PMActive.  You can calculate PMEndDate From Caldate with DateAdd(day, -1 * DAY(CalDate), CalDate).  We don't have much info of your table or tables to go on, and your existing attempt would be useful to see.

Comment: I've added the part of the code and the tables they come from.  Sorry for the viewing issues, this is my first time on this forum trying to make it look clear.

Comment: Please show what your data looks like.

Comment: It looks like the first three columns of the data output.  I don't know how to get the fourth column.  I've only ever been able to produce a fourth column exactly the same as the third.  The fourth column (PMActive) needs to be the Active total on 8/31/2018.